# No tv audio in Lubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, sound, lubuntu, pulseaudio, hdmi

I had to install Lubuntu ver. 16.04 (and not, say, 18.04) as my old machine wouldn't tolerate newer versions. Everything is working (and the machine seems to have had a burst of life) apart the TV audio. I have linked my machine to my TV through a HDMI cable that only carries the video signal (it is a DVI to HDMI cable, as my machine doesn't have a HDMI port); so, for the audio signal, I am using a separate audio cable.

About the sound:

- it works if I'm using an headset (both from the USB port and from the audio sockets in the front of my desktop PC)
- it actually works through the TV speakers the moment I remove the video cable
  from the HDMI TV socket and it stops working again if I plug the video cable back in.

so I am conjecturing that the HDMI signal gets in the way even if no audio is associated with it.

Furthermore, Pulseaudio seems to be working well as it is shown in the enclosed screenshot. I tried all the configuration choices in the Pulseaudio menu with no luck.

[image: audio panel]

here's also the gnome alsa mixer GUI.
[image: Alsa Mixer]

Final note: I have a dual boot system with Windows 7 and Lubuntu 16.04; and in Windows the TV audio (with the cable connections I have described above) works.

Comment: FYI: Lubuntu 16.04 LTS reached EOL in April 2019 ( https://lubuntu.me/test-xenial-6/ , http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/ ) along with all 16.04 flavors excluding Kylin. Yes the Ubuntu base is still supported, but GUI features are not unless you use Kylin or Unity (7) desktops and limit yourself to programs found in 'main' repo.  You can use `ubuntu-support-status` to see for yourself how much of your actual system is EOL.

Comment: thank you for your comment. I would have much preferred installing a more recent version but as I wrote in my post it didn't appear an option.

Comment: Following your advice I've run 'ubuntu-support-status':
                 

Support status summary of 'paolo-home-PC':

You have 1351 packages (76.2%) supported until aprile 2021 (Canonical - 5y)
You have 26 packages (1.5%) supported until aprile 2021 (Community - 5y)

You have 0 packages (0.0%) that can not/no-longer be downloaded
You have 397 packages (22.4%) that are unsupported

Comment: pulseaudio appears in the supported package list.

Comment: i never use `pulseaudio`, but probably you could try to modify volume parameter with `alsamixer` -> if you solve your issue with `alsamixer`, then you have to check default audio files

Comment: Thank you damadam. I have edited my post to include the gnome alsa mixer GUI. Can you advise which setting I should touch?